# Input field disappears when value length is 0 in React

Tags: reactjs

I have this component:

```
const SelectFieldOptions = ({ editedField, fieldMethods }: any) => {
  const items = editedField.fieldOptions.map((e: any) => {
    return (
      <div key={e.id}>
        <input type="text" onChange={() => fieldMethods.onOptionChange(e.id, event)} defaultValue={e.value} />
        <button id={e.id} onClick={fieldMethods.onOptionDelete}>
          X
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  });
  return <div>{items}<button onClick={fieldMethods.handleOptionSpawn}>New</button></div>;
```

And this function which handle onChange:

```
      case "optionValueChange":
        return {
          ...state,
          fieldOptions: state.fieldOptions.filter((el: any) =>
            action.payload.id === el.id
              ? (el.value = action.payload.value)
              : el
          )
        };
```

It is controlled input field type text and when it is backspaced to length 0, it just disappears from state. I would like to keep it there until it is deleted via a different function.

Thanks

Comment: The input disappears? Or the state variable disappears from developer tools?

Comment: Both. Input is created by the state with map function. It dissappear from state at first and then component is immediately rerendered without input aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change filter to map

```
state.fieldOptions.filter
```

becuse filter method is filtering values according what is callback returns, so if value is empty then this element is filtered out

With map it will not happen